# Class click won't trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/yTkTd/

Another function with a class works perfectly, but this one seems to be giving me trouble.  No console errors or anything, it just won't trigger.

EDIT: NEW JSFIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/yTkTd/9/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place [a `.delegate()` handler](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) on `#showList` so it will process the clicks for the dynamically created `.show` elements.

**Here's your updated example:** http://jsfiddle.net/yTkTd/11/

```
$('#showList').delegate('.show', 'click', function() {
    showID = $(this).attr("id");
    $(".show").fadeOut("slow");
    $(this).fadeIn("slow");
    $.getJSON('https://api.phish.net/api.js?api=2.0&method=pnet.shows.setlists.get&format=json&apikey=A9E68C2561D7442F041C&callback=?&showid='+showID, function pnet3setlist(data) {
        $('#showList').append("<div>");
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var n = data[i];
            $('#setList').append("<a class='show' href='#' id='setlist"+n['showid']+"'>"+n['setlistdata']+"</a>");
        }
        $('#showList').append("</div>");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.show` elements are added dynamically, after your click handler is attached. You should use `.live()` instead:

```
$(".show").live("click", function() {
    alert('hello');
});
```

This will behave the same, but causes jQuery to listen for click events at the document level (which is always there), but checks to see if the source element is a `".show"`.

Comment: @Switz, Now *that's* a different story ;) Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change the framework to jQuery. Currently Mootools is your library.

Comment: Well I have it included in my document (locally) and it's not triggering.  Any insight as to why that might be happening?

Comment: I see. Box9 is right. The click event is being added before the anchors are on the page.

Answer (score 0):

you had JSFiddle set to use mootools while you were using jQuery. I updated and ran and the click works fine... http://jsfiddle.net/yTkTd/6/